# Securing Admin Accounts - Username Discovery

Tags: admin, wp-admin, security

We've had [Limit Login Attempts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/) installed for some weeks now, and the number of brute force attempts occurring on wp-admin/wp-login is pretty amazing. At first the attempts were all with the username "Admin," which doesn't exist on our site, so I considered it an annoyance but not much of a threat. However, now we're seeing lockouts occurring with other named admin user accounts and I'm completely at a loss of understanding for how the attackers are deducing the usernames of these accounts.

No content on our site is authored by anyone in particular and I can't find any other location on our site where these usernames are publicly published.

Any idea as to how usernames might be discoverable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have pretty permalinks enabled WordPress will redirect all calls to `/?author=1` to the author archive with the user name, eg.: `/author/bob/`. And then the visitor will know the author name.

Use [Login Lockdown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-lockdown/), that plugin does not reset accounts, it will block IP addresses.

Comment: ["Limit Login Attempts blocks an Internet address from making further attempts after a specified limit on retries is reached... "](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/) I am not affiliated with the plugin but do use it and that is exactly what it appears to do. The IP address associated with a failed login is logged and the address is blocked if a configurable maximum attempt limit is reached. Also, "Login Lockdown" hasn't been updated in two years.

Answer (score 2):

Clever buggers. I think I am just going to redirect requests to /?author=. Sound reasonable? Something like:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_author_redirect' );
function my_author_redirect() {
    if ( is_author() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }       
}
```

Comment: That would be _Security by Obscurity_. It is better to configure your site so that it doesn't matter if a visitor knows your user name. The LLA plugins is breaking this essential rule; don't go the same way.

Comment: @toscho can you elaborate? I don't think the LLA plugin does completely break this rule. It works by initiating an IP lockout after x failed login attempts. It _does_ work even when an attacker knows the user name. What else can be done? Password protect wp-admin...whitelist only certain ip's with .htaccess...make sure all users have strong passwords...? Regardless of any/all of the above, I still like the above redirect option for belt-and-suspenders protection.

Comment: Maybe I remember this wrong. I had the impression that a certain user will be locked out after some failed log-in attempts.

Comment: Actually, crap you're right. I misspoke. The lockout is based on user.