# Increase of failed login attempts, brute force attacks?

Tags: login, security

I Installed the plugin Simple Login Lockdown and since a couple of days ago the database is recording over 200 records by day.

I think that is not possible to have my site attacked by so many IP's

Do you think there is something wrong?

Comment: Sure its possible. You know those people who click on everything without really paying attention to what they are clicking on? Blame them.

Comment: Do you guys know how to whitelist myself? I have overtested this plugin to the situation where I get the following: 

"Access denied. Your IP address [My IP] is blacklisted. If you feel this is in error please contact your hosting providers abuse department."

The readme tells something but I don't know how to correctly apply modifications and where. Which file to edit?

Answer (score 21):

There is currently a [botnet active, attacking WordPress and Joomla sites](http://www.siliconrepublic.com/strategy/item/32269-major-brute-force-attack/). And probably more. You *should* see more blocked logins. If you don’t, there is probably something wrong.

But be aware, blocking IP addresses doesn’t help against a bot net with more than 90,000 IP addresses.
And if you do that per plugin avoid **Limit Login Attempts**. It stores the IPs in a serialized option that has to be unserialized on each request. This is very expensive and slow.
Find a plugin that uses a separate database table or block the IP addresses in your .htaccess like this:

```
order allow,deny
# top 30 IP addresses listed in 
# http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/mass-wordpress-brute-force-attacks-myth-or-reality.html
deny from 31.184.238.38
deny from 178.151.216.53
deny from 91.224.160.143
deny from 195.128.126.6
deny from 85.114.133.118
deny from 177.125.184.8
deny from 89.233.216.203
deny from 89.233.216.209
deny from 109.230.246.37
deny from 188.175.122.21
deny from 46.119.127.1
deny from 176.57.216.198
deny from 173.38.155.22
deny from 67.229.59.202
deny from 94.242.237.101
deny from 209.73.151.64
deny from 212.175.14.114
deny from 78.154.105.23
deny from 50.116.27.19
deny from 195.128.126.114
deny from 78.153.216.56
deny from 31.202.217.135
deny from 204.93.60.182
deny from 173.38.155.8
deny from 204.93.60.75
deny from 50.117.59.3
deny from 209.73.151.229
deny from 216.172.147.251
deny from 204.93.60.57
deny from 94.199.51.7
deny from 204.93.60.185

allow from all
```

See also:

- [Codex: Brute Force Attacks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/brute-force-attacks/)
- [Login Protection With .htaccess](http://halfelf.org/2013/wp-login-protection-htaccess/) by Ipstenu (Mika Epstein)
- [Custom WordPress ModSecurity Rules](http://kb.liquidweb.com/wordpress-modsecurity-rules/) by Liquid Web
- [Protecting Against WordPress Brute-Force Attacks](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/protecting-against-wordpress-brute-force-attacks.html) by Sucuri Blog, also: [Mass WordPress Brute Force Attacks? – Myth or Reality](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/mass-wordpress-brute-force-attacks-myth-or-reality.html) with interesting statistical details
- [How to Password Protect the wp-login.php File](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/wordpress-login-brute-force-attack) by HostGator

Our tag [security](/questions/tagged/security) is also worth a look, especially:

- [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)
- [Securing Admin Accounts - Username Discovery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66223/securing-admin-accounts-username-discovery)
- [How brute-forcer knows that the password is cracked for target username?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87862/how-brute-forcer-knows-that-the-password-is-cracked-for-target-username)

If you have moved `wp-admin` or your `wp-login.php` these URLs can still be guessed by appending `/login` or `/admin` to the main URL. WordPress will redirect these requests to the correct location.
To stop that behavior you can use a very simple plugin:

```
<?php  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: No admin short URLs */

remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
```

I think this is *security by obscurity* – nothing serious.

Comment: I have numerous sites that get thousands on some days, it's entirely automated

Comment: We've seen a marked uptick in lockouts on our WordPress sites as well, join the club @Minapoli.

Comment: I use and love Limit Login Attempts, but in this case, it won't entirely help, because the botnet appears to be savvy enough only to try a handful of attempts with any given IP address. So, it effectively bypasses the per-IP lockout engaged by repeat login failures.

Comment: @Chip Bennett it seems to be only trying 'aaa', 'administrator' and 'admin' on our sites, are you seeing it any other usersnames being targeted?

Comment: I'm only aware of trying the `admin` username.

Comment: Ideally, I would imagine a locking system would be good. So, if a user gets more than x amount of failed logins, it gets locked for a set amount of time and only accessible if the user is on a known IP (taken from their previous successful logins).

Comment: One stupid question: Does keeping wordpress in another directory keep you away from those attacks? I guess they are only `targetting siteurl/wp-login.php` ?

Comment: @RRikesh Not sure. Usually `siteurl/login` redirects to the correct login page.

Comment: @RRikesh - No. Go to domain.com/wp-admin ... Oh look! That's where you moved login! You would have to move everything, and even then, you HAVE to be able to log in somehow, so moving the door doesn't help in the long run.

Comment: @Ipstenu If you keep WordPress in another directory, you'll have to login via `domain.com/directory/wp-admin`. However Toscho's suggestion of using `domain.com/login` instantly redirects to the actual login page(Even if you've installed WordPress in another directory).

Comment: @RRikesh - domain.com/admin on my site that has WP installed in a directory still works :/

Comment: I confirm that. `/login` redirects to `wp-login.php` and `/admin` redirects to `/wp-admin`.

Comment: @Ipstenu, RRikesh See my update. I will clean up these comments later.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [resources toscho listed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95577/251) in his answer, you could also use [PHP's Basic HTTP Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) to password protect wp-admin and or wp-login.php to block access to wp-login.php.

I just [released a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/password-protection/) that does this for you along with blocking No-Referrer requests. (The No-Refrrer block currently does not work for sites installed in a subdirectory).

Comment: Note that will lock out users with PHP running per (Fast-)CGI.

Comment: Thanks for that!  It works on PHP-FPM but after searching I see it won't work when php is running CGI/SuExec I'm going to have to make a quick update to deactivate the plugin in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your WordPress admin by following methods.

1. Add numbers,special characters and alphabets in your admin password then make **strong password**
2. If you got more records in your database, this will slow down your websites. So it can be avoid by adding **image captcha** in your wp-admin page. Some plugins are available for it. Like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts/