# How can I prevent redirects from mysite/page to mysite/wp path/page?

Tags: wp-admin, wp-redirect

Apparently this is built into WP somwhere since going to mysite/wp-login.php takes me to mysite/<wp path>/wp-login.php (same for wp-admin and I presume other paths).

The problem is, I don't like this functionality. My paths are intentionally not the default in order to make them less accessible to automated brute force attacks, but these redirects prevent the from being effective.

I'm assuming I can just filter this away, but I don't know which filter(s) would need to be used. Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hidden that in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95577/73), so I duplicate it here as a separate solution:

```
<?php  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: No admin short URLs */

remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );
```