# How to prevent wp-login brute force attack from thousand of different IP?

Tags: security, hacked

Investigating a problem. I found out that I had so many calls to `wp-login`, but from many different ip's. Any idea on how to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly it's not uncommon to receive many rogue login attempts. If you have a strong password policy this actually shouldn't worry you too much.

If there is a limited amount of people with logins and they work from fixed addresses, you can block acces to that page by [writing a rule in your `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range) that blocks all visitors from `wp-login.php` except those with certain ip-addresses.

Also, [security plugins like iThemes](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) can track rogue plugin attempts for you, and issue bans as well as fix common security loopholes. But you can't stop people from trying to get in, unless you decouple your site from the internet.

Comment: More on this here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95576/increase-of-failed-login-attempts-brute-force-attacks